# Select row name based on variable column and search criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following Excel spreadsheet:

```
     A                   B             C          D          E        F
1    KPI               Profit
2    Variancy            5%
3    Performance      very high
4
5    Description       Revenue       Costs       Profit
6    very low           -10%           -8%        -5%
7    low                 -5%           -3%        -2%
8    meaningless          0%            0%         0%  
9    high                 5%            3%         2%
10   very high           10%            8%         5%
11
12
```

The `Cell B1` and `B2` are input cells.

So far in `Cell B3` I use the following formular to get the `Description` from the table based on the Input in `Cell B2`:

```
=INDEX($A$5:$D$10,MATCH(B2,$D$5:$D$10,1),1)
```

All this works fine.

---

However, now my issue is that I also want to include `Cell B1` as variable into the formular so in case the user changes the input from `Profit` to `Revenue` the formular should automatically switch the column from `$D$5:$D$10` to `$B$5:$B$10`.

What do I have to change in my formula to make this work?

Comment: Do you want to call MATCH function with a different range B5:B10 in case B1 parameter changed to Revenue?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `IF` formula and check what is the value B1 cell. Depending on the result, change the parameters you pass to `MATCH` formula:

```
=INDEX($A$5:$D$10,IF($B$1="Revenue",MATCH(B2,$B$5:$B$10,1),MATCH(B2,$D$5:$D$10,1)),1)
```

Comment: @Michi Please look here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers